# Access the dependencies of a child module in a Gradle Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

We have a multi-module Spring Boot project.
Each has its own build.gradle.

We are trying to import the dependencies of module B in module A using:

```
implementation project(':moduleB')
```

inside the dependencies section of the build.gradle of module A.

There are no errors in IntelliJ while we are coding and using the classes of module B in module A.

However, running Gradle build tasks for module A fails with compilation exceptions, saying the respective package (which is present in module B) is not present.

Ideally the compilation errors would come up on the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies of a child module are not available to the compilation of a parent module if you use the `implementation` configuration when you declare those dependencies in the child module.

Instead, you have two choices:

1. Redeclare the dependencies you need in the parent module using the parent's `implementation` configuration, or
2. Declare the dependencies within the `api` configuration within the child module, like so:

```
// childModule/build.gradle

dependencies {
   api 'myDependencyGroup:myDependencyId:myDependencyVersion'
}
```

You can read more about these configurations in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) for the Java Library plugin.

Comment: even adding the 'api' configuration within the dependencies section of the child module did not help.